# jetty: put index.html into webroot

Tags: java, servlets, jetty

when started, jetty per default loads all directories and war-files in its webapps directory, that i can access via context path (e.g. http:// hostname/app/ to access the project in webapps/app.war).

Now when i open http:// hostname/ i get an 404 error and a list of the available contexts. To avoid that, i placed an index.html in the webapps directory and expected it to be returned when calling http:// hostname/. But i was wrong.

So how can i tell jetty what to return when accessing "/"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is to create a little webapp with your index page in it and to deploy that as the root context `/`. To do so, provide your own context file configuration.
Context files are normally located in `<jetty.home>/contexts/?.xml` (see [ContextDeployer](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/ContextDeployer) for more details).

Comment: The ContextDeployer link provided with this answer no longer works. If it has been moved, a new link is needed...